# How to HTTP GET a full dataset from ArcGIS WFS server?

Tags: arcgis-server, wfs, arcgis-rest-api

I would like to download [this data set](https://www.data.gv.at/katalog/dataset/cb3fb7aa-4b79-41b1-aeb9-cd60d575fe92) in a common format such as Shapefiles, GML, GeoJSON or another format which contains all information. An ArcGIS server is used to provide the data. I found the [GetCapabilities](http://geodaten1.graz.at/ArcGIS_Graz/services/Extern/OGD_WFS/MapServer/WFSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WFS) URL for the WFS but it does not expose the desired layer.
Single items from the layer set can be requested via an [HTML form](http://geodaten1.graz.at/ArcGIS_Graz/rest/services/Extern/OGD_WFS/MapServer/15/query). I could not find out how to request the full data set, though.

- [Example for item #26197](http://geodaten1.graz.at/ArcGIS_Graz/rest/services/Extern/OGD_WFS/MapServer/15/26197?f=json&pretty=true)

Answer (score 1):

I have written a python package to do this that can be [downloaded from GitHub](https://github.com/Bolton-and-Menk-GIS/restapi).  This package does not require ArcGIS/arcpy, but will use it if you have it available.  If not, it uses open source alternatives.  Once you download it, you should be able to extract the layer in question with the following code:

```
>>> import restapi
>>> url = 'http://geodaten1.graz.at/ArcGIS_Graz/rest/services/Extern/OGD_WFS/MapServer/15'
>>> lyr = restapi.MapServiceLayer(url)
>>> # export to shapefile on my desktop
>>> output = r'C:\Users\calebma\Desktop\test_export.shp'
>>> lyr.layer_to_fc(output) #will export the limit imposed by server, unless get_all param is true
```

And the results:

```
Created: "C:\Users\calebma\Desktop\test_export.shp"
<Result 'C:\\Users\\calebma\\Desktop\\test_export.shp'>
>>>
```

This feature class has over 17K records.  By default, services have a limit of 1000 features per request.  I tested on this and their limit was high enough that it allowed me to extract them all in one go.  It is also worth mentioning it supports attribute and spatial queries as well and you can limit what fields are returned.

Most of the time the default hasn't been changed and you can still extract them all if you wanted by setting the `get_all` parameter to true with the `restapi.MapServiceLayer.layer_to_fc()` method.  When this option is chosen, it will recursively make requests until all features are gathered before exporting.  There are some code examples on the GitHub page.  Each method has documentation as well so you can get the help like this:

```
>>> help(restapi.MapServiceLayer.layer_to_fc)
Help on method layer_to_fc in module restapi.arc_restapi:

layer_to_fc(self, out_fc, fields='*', where='1=1', records=None, params={'returnGeometry': 'true'}, get_all=False, sr=None) unbound restapi.arc_restapi.MapServiceLayer method
    Method to export a feature class from a service layer

    Required:
        out_fc -- full path to output feature class

    Optional:
        where -- optional where clause
        params -- dictionary of parameters for query
        fields -- list of fields for fc. If none specified, all fields are returned.
            Supports fields in list [] or comma separated string "field1,field2,.."
        records -- number of records to return. Default is none, will return maxRecordCount
        get_all -- option to get all records.  If true, will recursively query REST endpoint
            until all records have been gathered. Default is False.
        sr -- output spatial refrence (WKID)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an API, the documentation is in the top right corner of the site click the "?"  the Documentation for the Get can be [found here](http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.2/api.html#making-an-api-request) Then you will have to convert JSON to shape you can either use the ESRI tool or there are several open source options.

Comment: Your link points to the CKAN documentation?!

Comment: It's the API to access the data set provided by the site. RTM.